# Fitting probabilities for decision trees

Tags: probability, cart, decision-theory

I perform an **accident analysis** with decision trees.

Some cases are clear (all info exists), other ones haven’t it.

By my previous experience, I can add missing data (restoration costs). But I don’t know how to *adjust probabilities* for incomes *more mathematically* reasonably.
I could use the empirical probability for distinct incomes, but I can only predict a rough quantity of them.

The main problem is that our experiment **is over**, and I can't pick up a new necessary data.

What is the best way to solve this problem?